# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module Kodein-DI-kodein-di

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am building a kotlin MPP Library targeting JVM, Windows, JS and MacOS.

My gradle file looks like this for the JS

```
kotlin {
    targets {
        jvm()
        js {
            browser {
            }
            nodejs {
            }
        }

        mingwX64("windows") {
            binaries {
                sharedLib {
                    baseName = "lib"
                }
                staticLib {
                    baseName = "lib"
                }
            }
        }
        macosX64("macos") {
            binaries {
                sharedLib {
                    baseName = "lib"
                }
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            commonMain {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
                    implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di:$kodeinVersion")
                }
            }
            commonTest {
                dependencies {
                    implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                    implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
                    implementation("io.mockk:mockk-common:$mockkVersion")
                }
            }
            getByName("jvmMain").dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
            }
            getByName("jvmTest").dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion")
            }
            getByName("jsMain").dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
            }
            getByName("jsTest").dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
            getByName("macosMain").dependencies {
            }
            getByName("macosTest").dependencies {
            }
            getByName("windowsMain").dependencies {
            }
            getByName("windowsTest").dependencies {
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings.enableLanguageFeature("InlineClasses")
        }
    }
    configure(listOf(metadata(), jvm(), js(), macosX64("macos"), mingwX64("windows"))) {
        mavenPublication {
            val targetPublication = this@mavenPublication
            tasks.withType<AbstractPublishToMaven>()
                .matching { it.publication == targetPublication }
        }
    }
}

task("generateJsPackageJson") {
    doLast {
        File("$buildDir/js/packages/${project.name}/kotlin", "package.json")
            .writeText(
                """{
  "name": "@org/${project.name.toLowerCase()}",
  "version": "$version",
  "main": "${project.name}.js",
  "url": "https://gitlab.com/org/common/multiplatform/lib",
  "dependencies": {
    "kotlin": "^${kotlin.coreLibrariesVersion}"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
      "@org:registry":"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${System.getenv("CI_PROJECT_ID")}/packages/npm/"
    }
}
"""
            )
    }
}
```

The consumer of my library on JS install the package using npm from our GitLab registry and tha works fine. The issue they are experiencing is the following:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'Kodein-DI-kodein-di'
Require stack:
- /tmp/test-lib/node_modules/@org/lib/Index.js
- <repl>
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at /tmp/test-lib/node_modules/@org/lib/Index.js:5:48 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/tmp/test-lib/node_modules/@org/lib/Index.js',
    '<repl>'
  ]
}
```

How can I hide my dependency to Kodein to my JS clients? My understanding of how gradle dependency management works is that using implementation is supposed to add the dependency at compile and runtime but just for you module and not for its external clients.
Does this happen because I'm using KodeIN in non internal packages and classes of my Lib?

Answer (score 1):

It is because Kodein is Gradle (Maven) dependency, which is not presented in NPM registry.
You generate `package.json` with only Kotlin dependency, but without Kodein (and you can't because as I know, there is not Kodein in NPM).

In fact you need to distribute it with your code, because otherwise, you will get such `ReferenceError`

You can for example put you dependencies into `node_modules` dir inside you npm package.

Now we are working on Kotlin/JS IR compiler, which is based on closed world model, and which will produce JavaScript file with all Kotlin libraries bundled (but with possibility to share some in case). And you can try it with you project (if you dependencies have IR variant)

Comment: Thank you @ilya, what you are saying makes sense but also confirms my fears about targeting JS with Kotlin MPP. Can you elaborate a little more on the `You can for example put you dependencies into node_modules dir inside you npm package.` ?